# Microeconomics, price caps

Tags: microeconomics

My question is how does a price cap on  Rapid antigen tests (the one used to test for Covid 19) change the consumer and producer surplus in the short run assuming that the market for this product is perfectly competitive market?

Comment: Hi, I edited out the second question because opinion based questions are off topic on this site. See our help center for more details on that https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Since you make the strong assumption of perfect competition, how about making this question entirely theoretical and 'replacing rapid antigen tests' with 'a good'?

Comment: Also, consumer surplus is a somewhat weird metric to use for Covid tests, since the benefit of the test is mostly to other people, an externality. This is why some countries provide free tests.